# apache poi のCellStyle.setBorderBottomで引数をshortにせよとエラーが出てしまう

Tags: apache-poi

apache poi（バージョン3.17）を利用してエクセル出力しようといるのですが、The method setBorderBottom(short) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (BorderStyle)と表示されてしまい、コンパイルが出来ません。
poiのドキュメントを見る限りsetBorderBottomの引数はBorderStyleとなっているので、バージョンが食い違っている、ビルドパスが間違っている等を考え試しているのですが、うまくいかない状態です。

状況
1.マスターブランチにpoi2.5.1-final.jarが存在した状態
↓
2.エクセル出力のブランチへ変更、ビルドパスからpoi2.5.1-final.jarを削除、poi-3.17を追加
↓
3.出力処理作成（この時点ではコンパイル可能）
↓
4.一時的に別ブランチへ変更
↓
5.エクセル出力のブランチへ再度変更
↓
6.コンパイルエラー

試したこと
・ビルドパスを再設定（poi2.5.1を削除、poi3.17を追加）
・Eclipseを再起動
・ワークスペース再作成
など

わかっていないこと
・3.の時点でコンパイルできる状態のビルドパスにどのjarを入れていたか正確には覚えていない。

何かお分かりになる方、お力をお貸しいただけないでしょうか。

※追記「poi2.5.1を削除、poi3.17を追加」

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method setBorderBottom(short) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (BorderStyle)

このエラーは、`short`型の引数を渡すべきところで、`BorderStyle`型の引数を渡しているために発生しています。また、`setBorderBottom(BorderStyle)`はPOI 3.15で追加されていて、setBorderBottom(short)`がPOI 3.17から削除されています。つまり、古いバージョンのPOIを使用しているのに、新しいメソッドを呼び出すような実装をしているということになります。

Eclipseでコンパイルエラーとなっているプロジェクトを右クリックし、ビルドパスを見直してみて下さい。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ただ、試したことのビルドパスを再設定のところで古いバージョンのpoi-2.5.1は削除・poi3.17を追加をしている状態です。その状態でいまだにこのエラーが出てしまっていて、解決策が見出せていない状況です･･･

Comment: @kazu プロジェクトのJavaビルドパスの設定にpoi-2.5.1が無く、poi-3.17があることは確認できているということですか？それから、EclipseでCtrl+Shift+Tをクリックして、`CellStyle`と入力すると、何が表示されますか？

Comment: 確認してみました、poi-3.17とtila-app-1.13が出てきているのでこれが犯人のようです。Ctrl+Shift+Tのショートカット知りませんでした、ありがとうございます！

Comment: 調べたところ、apache tikaは内部でpoiを利用しており、（恐らくバージョン1.13が）poiの3.15以前を利用している。そのため発生していたようです。Ctrl+Shift+Tのショートカットも知らなかったですし、poiのビルドがおかしいという考えからも抜け出せていなかったので非常に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: そういうことでしたか。解決したようでしたら、回答を承認しておいて下さい。